# Figuring out how a number is represented in hex form

Tags: reverse-engineering, binaryfiles

Currently trying to essentially reverse engineer a file format that is produced by a CNC machine when backing up programs on the machine so that i can read the programs on a standard PC. Have opened a few of the backup files created and can clearly see patterns of data such as the program name etc. which can be clearly seen in plaintext form. One thing i am struggling with is how numbers are represented in this.

for Example: the number '20' is represented in this file in hex form as '40 0D 03 00'.

More examples:

"-213.6287": "21 67 DF FF"

"-500.3366": "9A A7 B3 FF"

Any help with trying to figure out how these hex values make up those numbers?

Thanks

Comment: If I was you I'd keep reversing - there is no way that `20` decimal has any direct correlation with `40 0D 03 00` hex. So maybe it isn't storing decimal amounts directly, maybe it's a vector or something else instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers are stored as little-endian signed integers, as a count of ten-thousandths.

> for Example: the number '20' is represented in this file in hex form as '40 0D 03 00'.

0x00030d40 = 200000.

> "-213.6287": "21 67 DF FF"

0xffdf6721 = -2136287.

> "-500.3366": "9A A7 B3 FF"

0xffb3a79a = -5003366.

Comment: Just realised this as i was analysising the hex values. How is the location of the decimal point decided in this though?

Comment: Based on the examples you've given, the scaling factor (of 10,000) may just be inherent to the format, or the device.

Comment: Yep seems like you're right! just had a scan through the rest of the file and you are right by saying its inherent to the format :) thank you so much for the help!